# Annotate in ggplot2 does not honor newline is a pasted and parsed command

Tags: r, ggplot2, vegan

#### Question

How do I get `paste` and `parse` in `annotate` of `ggplot2` to honor a newline (\n) character?

#### Problem and MWE

I am trying to reproduce in `ggplot2` a stressplot of an NMDS analysis using `metaMDS` in package `vegan.` Here is my MWE, followed by the resulting graph.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(tibble)
library(vegan)

set.seed(42) # for reproducibility

data(dune)
fit <- metaMDS(dune)
tib <- tibble(fit$diss, fit$dist, fit$dhat)
colnames(tib) <- c("diss", "dist", "dhat")
stress <- fit$stress
coord_x <- min(tib$diss)
coord_y <- max(tib$dist)
nonmetric_r2 <- round(1 - stress * stress, digits = 3)
linear_r2 <- round(summary(lm(fit$dist~fit$dhat))$adj.r.squared, 3)

## How do I get the newline character to be honored?
nonmetric_label = paste0("Non-metric~fit~italic(R)^2 ==", nonmetric_r2, "~\n Linear~fit~italic(R)^2 ==", linear_r2)

ggplot(tib,
       aes(x = diss, y = dist)) +
  geom_point(color = "blue") +
  geom_line(aes(x = diss, y = dhat), color = "red") +
  annotate(
    geom = "text",
    x = coord_x,
    y = coord_y,
    hjust = 0,
    #vjust = 1,
    label = nonmetric_label, parse = TRUE) +
  labs(x = "Observed Dissimilarity",
       y = "Ordination Distance")
```

[image]

The single annotated line above should be on two separate lines, as shown below (from `stressplot(fit)`).

[image: Stressplot produced using vegan's stressplot function.]

The offending line is

```
nonmetric_label = paste0("Non-metric~fit~italic(R)^2 ==", nonmetric_r2, "~\n Linear~fit~italic(R)^2 ==", linear_r2)
```

If I do not include the tilde before `\n`, then everything after the newline character disappears. I have tried various combinations of tilde placement and placing `'\n~Linear~fit'` in additional single quotes and back-ticks.

**How do I get the desired annotation to appear on two lines?**

Comment: plotmath doesn't support linebreaks. Maybe atop would suffice? See help("plotmath").

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One approach would be to use a vector of strings as a label and a vector of coordinates which will mach the desired annotation:

```
nonmetric_label = c(paste0("Non-metric~fit~italic(R)^2 ==", nonmetric_r2),
                    paste0("Linear~fit~italic(R)^2 ==", linear_r2)) 

ggplot(tib,
       aes(x = diss, y = dist)) +
  geom_point(color = "blue") +
  geom_step(aes(x = diss, y = dhat), color = "red", direction = "vh") +
  annotate(
    geom = "text",
    x = coord_x,
    y = c(coord_y, 0.95*coord_y),
    hjust = 0,
    #vjust = 1,
    label = nonmetric_label, parse = TRUE) +
  labs(x = "Observed Dissimilarity",
       y = "Ordination Distance")
```

[image]

As per suggestion of Jari Oksanen I have changed `geom_line` to `geom_step`. To match the output of `stressplot(fit)` an additional argument `direction = "vh"` is needed.

Comment: I think a bigger problem is that the step function is not a step function: the red line should have only horizontal and vertical segments, but it has sloping segments. Having text in one or two lines makes no difference.

Comment: @Jari Oksanen thanks for the comment. I completely agree with you. Changed `geom_line` to `geom_step`.

Comment: @JariOksanen I agree that the number of lines for the text does not matter, but I think it is aesthetically more pleasing on two lines. Thanks for info regarding the step function and missuse for the change.

Comment: I struck me this morning that the philosophy of `ggplot2` is to build up a graph in layers. I moved each annotation to it's own `annotate` command, which also gives me greater flexibility. Your line `y = c(coord_y, 0.95*coord_y)` showed me how to get good spacing. So, thank you for your time and answer.